# Retrofit errorBody() should return Optional

Tags: retrofit

Let's say I have a test with following assertion:

```
assertThat(response.isSuccess()).as(response.errorBody().string()).isTrue();
```

it will throw NullPointerException when response is success therefore test never passes.

I needed to make soemthing like this:

```
String errorDescription = response.errorBody() == null ? "" : response.errorBody().string();
assertThat(response.isSuccess()).as(errorDescription).isTrue();
```

which is ugly. Is it possible for errorBody to be wrapped in optional or maybe there is a better way for doing this?

Comment: Error body will be null if the request is successful.

Comment: That'a exactly what I claimed in my post. The reason why I wrote it was to ask whether retrofit creators can change their api to return optional instead null (I know they are stracking stackoverflow posts with retrofit tag), or maybe someone else know an alternative to this workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone deleted my answer to that saying that I provided only url to github where it was answered. This was my answer to post:

Answered on github of Retrofit: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1304

**Optionals are not available on Android.**

This time I emphasized actual answer so it will not be deleted again.